# Updating records and their associations with sequelize

Tags: sqlite, associations, sequelize.js

I have the following models defined in sequelize:

**Library**, **MediaParentDir**, **MediaSubDir** and **MediaSubDirEpisodes**

The first three hold information about directories on the system and the last one holds information about files in a particular directory on the system.

The associations are as follows:

```
Library.MediaParentDirs = Library.hasMany(models.MediaParentDir, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
Library.MediaSubDirs = Library.hasMany(models.MediaSubDir, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'});

MediaParentDir.MediaSubDirs = MediaParentDir.hasMany(models.MediaSubDir, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'});

MediaSubDir.Episodes = MediaSubDir.hasMany(models.Episode, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
```

And this is how I populate the database on first run:

```
db.Library.find({
    where: lib
}).then((existingLib) => {

    let includes = [{
            model: db.MediaParentDir,
            include: [{
                model: db.MediaSubDir,
                include: [db.Episode]
            }]
        },
        {
            model: db.MediaSubDir,
            include: [db.Episode]
        }
    ];

    let mediaParentDirs = removeIgnored(library.getMediaParentDirsFrom(lib))
        .map((parentDir) => {
            parentDir.MediaSubDirs = removeIgnored(library.getMediaSubDirsFrom(parentDir));
            parentDir.MediaSubDirs.map((subDir) => {
                subDir.Episodes = removeIgnored(library.getMediaSubDirEpisodesFrom(subDir));
                return subDir;
            });
            return parentDir;
        });


    let mediaSubDirs = removeIgnored(library.getMediaSubDirsFrom(lib))
        .map((subDir) => {
            subDir.Episodes = removeIgnored(library.getMediaSubDirEpisodesFrom(subDir));
            return subDir;
        });

    let updatedLib = db.Library.build({
        name: lib.name,
        path: lib.path,
        type: lib.type,
        // Add all media parent dirs and child sub dirs under media parent dirs
        MediaParentDirs: mediaParentDirs,
        // Add all media sub dirs directly under library
        MediaSubDirs: mediaSubDirs,
    }, {
        include: includes
    });


    if (!existingLib)
        return updatedLib.save();

    // Record already exists. Update library data.

});
```

In the code above, I'm reading the library directory and gathering all the information about MediaParentDirs and other models mentioned previously. Finally, I build a Library instance with all the nested associations defined.

Now, if a library already exists, I need to update the data associated to it and its models. I already tried a few things:

- `Library.upsert()` but this doesn't update the associations.
- `Library.update()` same as above.
- `embed.update()` from https://github.com/Wsiegenthaler/sequelize-embed but this requires me to supply object IDs explicitly

Is there any other way I could update the associated model instances?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize automatically [adds setter methods](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations) to models that can be used to update associated data in the database.

Following is the code that I use to list the methods. Add this in index.js after associations are defined and restart node server.

```
   for (let assoc of Object.keys(db[modelName].associations)) {
    for (let accessor of Object.keys(db[modelName].associations[assoc].accessors)) {
      console.log(db[modelName].name + '.' + db[modelName].associations[assoc].accessors[accessor]+'()');
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the setters in this case are used to associate two already existing records. I'm trying to update data in the already associated records.